# Fluid Featured Post Carousel Slider for Wordpress with no Javascript

Tags: php

I implemented a pure CSS Slider without Javascript on my Test-site with 5 image slides. How can i adapt the slider to show the 5 latest posts from my featured post category with thumb, title, excerpt and link to the post instead of the images?

Thank you so much

[**Here is the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lt59w3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=carousel>
        <ul class=panes>    
<?php 
// the query
$args = array('cat' => id_of_featured_posts_category, 'posts_per_page' => 5);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full'); ?>
            </li>


    <?php endwhile; ?>



  <?php endif; ?>
 </ul>
    </div>
```

I don't have wordpress here to test it, but it should work, to learn more about this you can check the documentation for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I don't know where you want to add the excerpt (the_excerpt() is the function you need to call to get it), but I'm sure you can take from here.